# Resolve Azure Private DNS zone entry from domain joined VM

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

We have a virtual machine created in Azure which is using a private VNet configured with custom DNS servers in order to domain join the VM (eg. contoso.com)

Now we have a private DNS zone (eg subdomain.contoso.com) created in Azure which is linked to the same VNet as the VM. However, we are not able to resolve the private DNS entries from within the domain joined VM as I believe, Azure query the Azure private DNS with the IP 168.63.129.16

Is there a way we can forward DNS requests from a VM in Azure VNet using custom DNS servers to Azure private DNS zone linked to the same VNet?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using Azure Private DNS, you can resolve domain names in a virtual network without the need to add a custom DNS solution.

By using private DNS zones, you can use your own custom domain names rather than the Azure-provided names available today

> Is there a way we can forward DNS requests from a VM in Azure VNet
> using custom DNS servers to Azure private DNS zone linked to the same
> VNet?

If you have created custom DNS private zone, you can enable **Autoregistration** feature so that DNS requests from your VM in the VNET will be forwarded to the Azure private DNS zone